# How to call a scheduled job from scoped application om servicenow?

Tags: servicenow

I am trying to call scheduled job from my UI action in my scoped application. But it gives me an error saying "SncTriggerSynchronizer is not allowed in scoped applications".
Here is my code:

```
    var rec = new GlideRecord('sysauto_script');
    rec.get('name', 'Load Micello Files');
    SncTriggerSynchronizer.executeNow(rec);
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can overcome this error?

Thanks

Comment: Answered at https://community.servicenow.com/message/867892

Answer (score 0):

I just spent about an hour researching. I tried using a global script include that's available across all scopes to execute a scheduled job; I tried calling it via package and about a half dozen other things. I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you're looking to do. Unfortunately, ServiceNow really crippled what developers are able to do within the context of scoped apps, which is why I generally don't bother with them anymore.

We may be able to help you work around it if we had some more context as to what exactly you're trying to do.

For example, is there a reason you're using a scheduled job rather than a script include or something along those lines for this functionality? What functionality are you trying to enable?

---

EDIT: I just had an idea about adding a sys_trigger item for like gs.now().add(5000), or something like that.

Working on it, will update this post momentarily once I know if it works.

---

EDIT2: Okay, this may or may not work. It seems to work on my instance, but please give it a go and let me know what you think.

```
//Get your scoped scheduled job record here. 
action.setRedirectURL(current);
var rec = new GlideRecord('sysauto_script');
rec.get('89005b244f1d9200bf004a318110c7b2');
//Get a GDT set to 10 seconds from now.
var gdt = new GlideDateTime(gs.nowDateTime());
var now = gdt.getValue();
gdt.add(10000);
var tenSecondsFromNow = gdt.getValue();
//Create a new trigger record
var trig = new GlideRecord('sys_trigger');
trig.initialize();
trig.name = reg.getValue('name');
trig.next_action = tenSecondsFromNow;
trig.error_count = '0';
trig.job_context = '#' + now + '\nfcDocumentClass=sysauto_script\nfcDocumentKey=' + rec.getValue('sys_id');
trig.trigger_type = '0';    //0 = Run Once
trig.state = '0';   //0 = Ready
trig.document = 'sysauto_script';
trig.document_key = rec.getValue('sys_id');
trig.log('false');
trig.next_action = tenSecondsFromNow;
trig.priority = '100';
trig.run_count = '0';
trig.run_dayofmonth = '1';
trig.run_dayofweek = '1';
trig.run_time = '1970-01-01 08:00:00';
trig.trigger_class = 'com.snc.automation.ScriptJob';
trig.upgrade_safe = 'false';
trig.insert();
```

Basically, we're manually creating a trigger record for ten seconds in the future. This bypasses the need for the SncTriggerSynchronizer which is INEXPLICABLY blocked in scoped applications (UGH!!).

Good luck, my friend. ^_^

Comment: Unfortunately this also will not work by default, because the "sys_trigger" table access is limited to read from scoped applications. You could add create to the table to work around this, which violates SN certification guidelines.

Comment: Scoped apps are so completely crippled, I'm so very glad I don't have to work with them myself.

Good catch, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For scoped apps you need to change:

```
 SncTriggerSynchronizer.executeNow(rec);
```

To:

```
gs.executeNow(rec);
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. Thank you.